# How can I set the system proxy in React-Native?

Tags: android, react-native

I would like to write a native application that starts a proxy and sets the system proxy to point to my proxy.

Is there an API to allow me to set the system proxy? Maybe platform-specific? I'm mainly interested on Android, but having it for other platforms would be a plus.

Comment: I have no idea what that means.

Comment: I mean to redirect all network traffic through a network proxy.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I haven't :-/. I don't think React-Native has an API for that.